# Reset Google Chrome browser on each startup

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, google

I have Ubuntu machines that will be used by students and I would like it that every time google chrome is closed and reopened it reset to default settings. Do any of you know where to set that up?

Comment: Do you need to keep any files created by the students when they are done on the machine? Or is everything online or something else?

Comment: It's unclear (at least to me) what you are attempting to accomplish. Some settings you may wish to persist for a variety of reasons. Normal procedure would be to keep settings for each user separately.